How to get the tagName on particular event like focus and blur
I have tried this with multiple scenarios mention in the code, I just want to get the tagName on specific events like blur and focus. The steps I tried also mention in the code.
window.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.tagName) //undefined
    clearTimeout(focusTimeout) // Clear previous timeout if any
    focusTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      handleVisibilityChange(1)
      connectTab()
    }, 100) // Wait for 100 milliseconds before reacting to focus
  })

  window.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
    console.log('Blurrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr: event called')

    const blurredElement = event.target
    console.log('Blurred element:', blurredElement)
    console.log('Blurred element:', event.target.tagName) //undefined

    handleVisibilityChange(0)
    disconnectTab()
    session_id = generateSessionId()
  }) 

What can I try next?

window focus/blur is triggered when the window is focused or blurred - there is no tagName for window

You are only ever capturing blur and focus events that occur on the window object itself here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event#event_delegation:

Event delegation.
There are two ways of implementing event delegation for this event: by using the focusout event, or by setting the useCapture parameter of addEventListener() to true.

And the same goes for the focus event.
So add true as third parameter in your addEventListener calls.

First thanks for your quick reply. I have added third parameter and tried it but it not works it still console me undefined. Can you suggest me the code if it is possible.

https://jsfiddle.net/rdnz5twj/ - this will still fire blur and focus events for the window itself, in addition to any elements that might gain/lose focus. If you don't want the window events - then subscribe on document instead of window, https://jsfiddle.net/rdnz5twj/1/

okay that's working fine but not for all the elements I think can you please look into this jsfiddle snippt that I attached I'm trying it with ifram its not detected https://jsfiddle.net/8fg7rudL/

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve there; but reacting to anything inside that 3rd-party iframe getting/losing focus, won't be possible. You can not interact with iframe content that was loaded from a different origin like that.

I want to achieve is my js is working on page fine but when there is any iframe is embedded and user click on it then the blur event called that why I want to try to get the element so that if it detects it's an iframe then I didn't call the function that are inside the blur event

Then you will probably have to check if the event target is the current window object, instead of looking for an element and a specific element name. https://jsfiddle.net/4ufqs2h6/
